# Simple question about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X, Y,$ and $Z$ be random variables. Assume $X$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$. I know that $E[X|Z]=E[X]$. But is it true that $E[XY|Z]=E[X]*E[Y|Z]$?

Sorry for not using formatting.

Comment: I think so, via $E[XY|Z]=E[X|Z]E[Y|Z]=E[X]E[Y|Z]$. The first equality should follow by independence of $X 1_A$ and $Y 1_A$ for $Z$-measurable sets $A$.

Comment: You could also use iterated expectations: $E[XY|Z]=E[E[XY|Z,Y]|Z]=E[YE[X|Z,Y]|Z]=E[YE[X]|Z]=E[X]E[Y|Z]$.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are very clear and nice.